# Installing Google's ios-webkit-debug-proxy

Tags: ios, linux, debugging, ubuntu, google-chrome-devtools

I'm attempting to get google's ios webkit debug proxy working on my laptop, running ubuntu 15.04.

https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy

I've followed their installation instructions as best I could. However, I'm new to both web development and linux and am having trouble at the step where I run `./autogen.sh`.

It runs its checks for a while, but then I receive the following error from the terminal:

> checking for libimobiledevice... no
>   configure: error: Package requirements (libimobiledevice-1.0 >= 1.2.0) were not met:
>
> Requested 'libimobiledevice-1.0 >= 1.2.0' but version of libimobiledevice is 1.1.6
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
>   installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libimobiledevice_CFLAGS
>   and libimobiledevice_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
>   See the pkg-config man page for more details.

I've tried my luck with troubleshooting this on my own but can't figure it out.

Anyone out there familiar with this error and what it wants me to do? Is my file-path messed up or do I need a different version of libimobiledevice (which I believe I have the most updated one)?

Comment: did u figure this out? ive same issue

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you need libimobiledevice 1.2 or higher. Compiling it from source is a solution:

- Download libimobiledevice 1.2: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/downloads/libimobiledevice-1.2.0.tar.bz2
- Extract: `tar xf libimobiledevice-1.2.0.tar.bz2`
- `cd libimobiledevice-1.2.0`
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`

You should now be able to successfully build ios-webkit-debug-proxy.

You may need to run `sudo ldconfig` afterwards to update the library cache.

Comment: I must have `libusbmuxd-2.0` installed, how do I get it?